# How to join two tables using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables -  `positions` table with the fields `id`, `position_id`, `first_name` and  `last_name`. The other table is `positionslist` with the fields `id`, `positions`.How will i able to join that two tables?
Here's my positionscontroller:

```
class PositionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #@positions = Position.all(:order=>'updated_at DESC')
    @positions = Position.joins(:positions => :positionlists)
  end
  def new
    @position = Position.new
  end

  def create
    @position = Position.new(params.require(:position).permit(:position_id, :first_name, :last_name))
    if @position.save
      redirect_to(:controller=>'positions')
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @position = Position.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @position = Position.find(params[:id])
    if @position.update(params.require(:position).permit(:position_id, :first_name, :last_name))
      redirect_to(:controller=>'positions')
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @position = Position.find(params[:id])
    @position.destroy
    redirect_to(:controller=>'positions')
  end
end
```

my models position.rb

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positionlists
  has_many :positionlists , :through => :positions
  validates :first_name, length: { in: 4..20}
  validates :last_name, length: { in: 4..20}
end
```

my models positionlists.rb

```
class Positionlists < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
end
```

any my postions index.html.erb

```
<% content_for :title, "Positions" %>
  <%= render "layouts/nav" %>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <h1>Positions List</h1>
  <%= link_to "Add", new_position_path, :class =>'btn btn-success' %>
  <br />
  <br />
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    <% @positions.each do |positions| %>

    <tr>
      <td><%= positions.first_name %></td>
      <td><%= positions.last_name %></td>
      <td><%= positions.position_id %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_position_path(positions)%> |
        <%= link_to "Delete", position_path(positions),
                              method: :delete, data:{confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this?.' }%>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

any help is greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: In `Positionlists.rb` model, did you mean `belongs_to :position`? Also note the singular usage. It's `:position` and not `:positions`. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: im trying to join the two tables which are the table positions and table positionslist

Comment: did you create these tables using a rails migration, or by hand?

Comment: rails migration by rake:db migrate

Comment: There are a few problems here - I'll add more context to the answer...

Comment: what is a position_list here?  is it just a collection of positions?  will it have any other attributes?  or are you just trying to get a list of all positions for your positions controller?

Comment: positionLists fields are id and postion

Comment: inside that table eg: id-1 postion: sysad

Comment: trying to get a list of all positions also

Comment: see answers below - that's about as much as we can do in Stack Overflow - I think you may benefit from following the link to the tutorial that I've put in the answer, as it'll help you with a more idiomatic "rails way" for doing this.

Comment: thanks @richard Jordan

Comment: the check mark is the only thanks anyone needs on here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails takes care of this for you.

```
class PositionList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
end

class Position < ActiveRecrod::Base
  belongs_to :position_list
end
```

Also your `position` needs a `position_list_id` column for simplicity. If I'm understanding what you are trying to do here.

Other problems: naming your class `PositionLists` and not `PositionList` will confuse Rails automagic naming conventions.

Also you have an odd set of columns in your tables.  For what you want as far as I can tell your positions table needs to have the columns:

```
first_name
last_name
id (automatic)
```

You don't appear to have anything in your position_list table so there's no column you need there outside of the automatic id column.  The association is automatic from the belongs_to in the `Position` class and the `position_list_id` column in the positions table.

If you want to get an idea of how simple this all can be try running an automatic scaffolding, looking at how it's done there, and learning from that.  Maybe a generate a fresh Rails app and then run something like this:

```
rails g scaffold position_list name
rails g scaffold position first_name last_name position_list:references
```

This will give you `position_list.positions` to get all positions for any position_list or Position.all for a list of all positions.

Also it sounds like a lot of Rails is new to you.  Hartl's classic is a great intro: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: this is what i get
Association named 'positions' was not found on Position; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: are you just trying to have two classes - a PositionList which can contain many Positions? from your code I'm just trying to see what you're trying to achieve so I can post the code you need as there appear to be quite a few issues with the code you posted in the question... just trying to hone in on the right one.

Comment: who deleted all the explanation that the questioner clearly needs in the edit process?